# How to optimize hair rendering?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, hair, denoise

[image: sampling with 4096]

I'm rendering a character animation with particle hair in Cycles, but no matter how I increase sampling, the hair is still not clear as the rest part of body.

I've tried to render with 100\1024\2048\4096\16K sampling. It looks better at 16k, but render time is too long for animation.

How could I get acceptable render time with low sample number?

Comment: Honestly, I would keep the previous images in your question. It's hard to tell what's in the current crop of images.

Comment: the project where this image belong is not public for now, I`ll switch image back as soon as project released.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the low value of roughness of Principled hair shader. Low roughness will cause high gloss and require high glossy sampling, which cost tons of extra time. And it`s solved after re-arrange the hair shader.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what settings you are talking about and where they are. This is a community for beginners too. A more detailed answer would be appreciated by all users